# RAID-1 HDD data access in another system

Tags: raid-1

I have Dell Power Edge R210 ii with RAID 1 implemented (2 x 1TB) and windows server 2008 R2.
My server got some hardware issues which is not booting and I tried to connect hard drives to a windows 10 system as external and there both of hard drives are detected but cant access them and also their partition is not listed as well.
Any way to access the data of these hard drives?

Comment: What is the service tag of the failing PowerEdge, and have you made any changes to factory hardware (I want the tag to look up the model of PERC controller it has).   In my experience [ with Linux, on R210 systems with the H330 controller], you should be able to put the drives into another PERC controller system and have them work - but again, if they are in RAID 1 I would expect them to be readable individually, and off  a standard controller.  How did you attach the drives to the new system?

Comment: There are multiple errors with server hardware. For now server is not important, I just want to access the data exist in Hard drive. And I didn't changed anything in hardware and software of the power edge server. I attached these hard drives directly to my computer board. It is listed in BIOS and also visible in disk management of windows 10 but no drive letter and when I want to assign drive letter those options are disable.

Comment: And also these hard drives containing two partition. In windows disk management console even the partitions are not visible.

Comment: Find another PERC controller and try plugging the drives into that.  Alternatively - and this carries some risk and is by no means guaranteed - clone one of the disks to a fresh disk using dd or ddrescue or similar, then try run testdisk on it to see if it can identify partition starts and rebuild a partition table.  You only need to do this on 1 of the 2 disks as they should contain almost identical data.

Comment: How to use dd or ddrescue while the hard drives has no drive letter?

Comment: Please dont take offense, but I strongly recommend you take your data to a recovery specialist.   If this thread is anything to go by you don't have anything like the knowledge you need to retrieve your data, and I assume its more then "just cat photos" if its a 1u server.. (I strongly suggest you do not do anything further on the drives as you risk making things worse - but the answer to your question would be "boot a Linux disk, then identify drives from dmesg output, /dev entries, lsblk or identify them using educated guesses and hdparm or smartctl ")

Comment: Unfortunately here is not Data Recovery specialist exist in our location. There are important data i need to copy from these hard drives

Comment: I forgot to mention. I tried both external attach and attaching to board

Comment: Then put each of the drives in an anti-static bag, put a lot of padding around each - I mean a LOT), and courier them separately - either with different companies or sequentially -  (with signature required courier + insurance) to a data recovery specialist.   If its not worth the cost/delay, find your closest Linux Users Group and pay an experienced person to attempt recovery for you, or pay DELL to fix your hardware.  If you still want to proceed to do it yourself - which I believe is reckless, and likely to make problems worse - move this to chat and I'll talk you through it some more.

Comment: Ok. I will try other ways if I couldn't find the solution then I will choose to chat with u